# How to pass parameters to an API url from JS

Tags: javascript

Hello i have this api url

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/outlay`

that brings default values now i want to add filters to this url i tried to follow the example of postman that does it like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/outlay?startdate=2023-02-14&enddate=2023-02-15
```

This is what i tried but didnt work:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/outlay?startdate='startdateOutlay'&enddate='enddateOutlay'
```

The `startdateOutlay` and `enddateOutlay` are calendar input that change value dynamically, is it possible to do such a thing from `Javascript`?

Comment: that's a [GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request and you can use the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). If you need help on that, there are surely tons of question on that realm here on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use template string ``

```
const apiUrl = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/outlay?startdate=${startdateOutlay}&enddate=${enddateOutlay}`;
```